# Combining multiple similar queries into 1

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I have the following queries in some python code,

```
    sel = select([staff.c.name,
                      staff.c.start_date,
                      staff.c.leave_allowance,
                      ]) \
            .select_from(staff) \
            .where(staff.c.name == request.args.get('user')) \
            .group_by(staff.c.name, staff.c.leave_allowance, staff.c.start_date)

        staff_member = ZS.db_connect().execute(sel).fetchone()
        staff_member = dict(staff_member)

sel1 = select([staff.c.start_date,
                func.sum(leave.c.hours).label('hours_taken')
                ]) \
        .select_from(join(staff, leave, (staff.c.name == leave.c.name))) \
        .where(leave.c.leave_start >= '2016-01-01') \
        .where(leave.c.leave_end <= '2016-03-30') \
        .where(leave.c.hr_status == 'RP_Approved') \
        .where(leave.c.name == request.args.get('user')) \
        .group_by(staff.c.name, staff.c.start_date)

        jan_user = ZS.db_connect().execute(sel1).fetchone()
        if(jan_user):
            jan_user = dict(jan_user)
            staff_member['JanMarTaken'] = jan_user['hours_taken']
        else:

            staff_member['JanMarTaken'] = 0

        sel2 = select([staff.c.start_date,
                func.sum(leave.c.hours).label('hours_taken')
                ]) \
            .select_from(join(staff, leave, (staff.c.name == leave.c.name))) \
            .where(leave.c.leave_start >= '2016-04-01') \
            .where(leave.c.leave_end <= '2016-09-30') \
            .where(leave.c.hr_status == 'RP_Approved') \
            .where(leave.c.name == request.args.get('user')) \
            .group_by(staff.c.name, staff.c.start_date)

        mar_user = ZS.db_connect().execute(sel2).fetchone()
        if(mar_user):
            mar_user = dict(mar_user)
            staff_member['MarSeptHours'] = mar_user['hours_taken']
        else:
            staff_member['MarSeptHours'] = 0


        sel2 = select([staff.c.start_date,
                func.sum(leave.c.hours).label('hours_taken')
                ]) \
            .select_from(join(staff, leave, (staff.c.name == leave.c.name))) \
            .where(leave.c.leave_start >= '2016-10-01') \
            .where(leave.c.leave_end <= '2016-12-31') \
            .where(leave.c.hr_status == 'RP_Approved') \
            .where(leave.c.name == request.args.get('user')) \
            .group_by(staff.c.name, staff.c.start_date)

        oct_user = ZS.db_connect().execute(sel2).fetchone()
        if(oct_user):
            mar_user = dict(mar_user)
            staff_member['OctDecHours'] = mar_user['hours_taken']
        else:
            staff_member['OctDecHours'] = 0
```

The queries all do the same thing basically which is search a for user by name and retrieve some data that is logged between certain dates, I need the data for 3 segments of the year, so currently I am query the database 3 times with different date parameters, is there a way I could do this with 1 query, for better performance?

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in SQL, so you could convert into a stored proc, I added a variable @YearToCheck to pass in the report year.

Lets make some test data:

```
DECLARE @Staff TABLE
(
    Name VARCHAR(100),
    Emp_Start_Date DATETIME,
    Emp_End_Date DATETIME,
    Emp_Leave_Allowance INT
)

DECLARE @Leave TABLE
(
    Name VARCHAR(100),
    Leave_Start DATETIME,
    Leave_End DATETIME,
    Hr_Status VARCHAR(100)
)

DECLARE @YearToCheck INT = 2016

INSERT INTO @Staff 
( Name, Emp_Start_Date, Emp_End_Date, Emp_Leave_Allowance )
VALUES
( 'Fred', DATEFROMPARTS( 2016, 1, 3 ), NULL, 10 ),
( 'Wilma', DATEFROMPARTS( 2014, 2, 1 ), NULL, 10 ),
( 'Barney', DATEFROMPARTS( 2015, 7, 1 ), NULL, 10 ),
( 'Betty', DATEFROMPARTS( 2014, 2, 1 ), NULL, 10 );

INSERT INTO @Leave
( Name, Leave_Start, Leave_End, Hr_Status )
VALUES
( 'Fred', DATEFROMPARTS( 2015, 12, 1), DATEFROMPARTS( 2016, 6, 1), 'RP_Approved'),
( 'Fred', DATEFROMPARTS( 2016, 7, 1), DATEFROMPARTS( 2016, 8, 1), 'RP_Approved'),
( 'Wilma', DATEFROMPARTS( 2016, 1, 10), DATEFROMPARTS( 2016, 1, 15), 'RP_Approved'),
( 'Barney', DATEFROMPARTS( 2016, 6, 10), DATEFROMPARTS( 2016, 7, 10), 'RP_Approved'),
( 'Betty', DATEFROMPARTS( 2016, 7, 30), DATEFROMPARTS( 2016, 8, 5), 'RP_Approved'),
( 'Betty', DATEFROMPARTS( 2016, 9, 29), DATEFROMPARTS( 2016, 10, 3), 'RP_Approved'),
( 'Betty', DATEFROMPARTS( 2015, 1, 1), DATEFROMPARTS( 2017, 1, 5), 'RP_Approved');
```

Now lets run a query looking for the different date partitions

Section 1: 1-1 to < 4-1 (you had 3/30 for some reason, but march ends in 3/31?)

Section 2: 4-1 to < 10-1

Section 3: 10-1 to < 1-1 (of next year)

```
SELECT s.Name,      
        CASE WHEN (l.Leave_Start <= DATEFROMPARTS( @YearToCheck, 4, 1)) AND (DATEFROMPARTS( @YearToCheck, 1, 1) <= l.Leave_End)  
            THEN
                DATEDIFF( DAY, 
                    CASE WHEN l.Leave_Start < DATEFROMPARTS( @YearToCheck, 1, 1) THEN DATEFROMPARTS( @YearToCheck, 1, 1) ELSE l.Leave_Start END,
                    CASE WHEN l.Leave_End > DATEFROMPARTS( @YearToCheck, 4, 1) THEN DATEFROMPARTS( @YearToCheck, 4, 1) ELSE DATEADD(DAY, 1, l.Leave_End) END ) --Inclusive
            ELSE 0
        END AS FirstSection,
        CASE WHEN (l.Leave_Start <= DATEFROMPARTS( @YearToCheck, 10, 1)) AND (DATEFROMPARTS( @YearToCheck, 4, 1) <= l.Leave_End)  
            THEN
                DATEDIFF( DAY, 
                    CASE WHEN l.Leave_Start < DATEFROMPARTS( @YearToCheck, 4, 1) THEN DATEFROMPARTS( @YearToCheck, 4, 1) ELSE l.Leave_Start END,
                    CASE WHEN l.Leave_End > DATEFROMPARTS( @YearToCheck, 10, 1) THEN DATEFROMPARTS( @YearToCheck, 10, 1) ELSE DATEADD(DAY, 1, l.Leave_End) END ) --Inclusive
            ELSE 0
        END AS SecondSection,
        CASE WHEN (l.Leave_Start <= DATEFROMPARTS( @YearToCheck + 1, 1, 1)) AND (DATEFROMPARTS( @YearToCheck, 10, 1) <= l.Leave_End)  
            THEN
                DATEDIFF( DAY, 
                    CASE WHEN l.Leave_Start < DATEFROMPARTS( @YearToCheck, 10, 1) THEN DATEFROMPARTS( @YearToCheck, 10, 1) ELSE l.Leave_Start END,
                    CASE WHEN l.Leave_End > DATEFROMPARTS( @YearToCheck + 1, 1, 1) THEN DATEFROMPARTS( @YearToCheck + 1, 1, 1) ELSE DATEADD(DAY, 1, l.Leave_End) END ) --Inclusive
            ELSE 0
        END AS ThirdSection
    FROM @Staff s
    INNER JOIN @Leave l
        ON l.Name = s.Name
    WHERE l.Hr_Status = 'RP_Approved'
```

Here is the output data by days:

```
Name    FirstSection    SecondSection   ThirdSection
Fred    91  62  0
Fred    0   32  0
Wilma   6   0   0
Barney  0   31  0
Betty   0   7   0
Betty   0   2   3
Betty   91  183 92
```

Now, I don't check if the vacation ranges overlap, or if the days overlap weekends, etc... since that wasn't in the question, that could be added, but hopefully this is something you can use to pull the logic out of python and let the sql server handle the work.